# objects displaying in other cell rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview, object, location, exchange-server

i have asked this question previous ,now more clearly i will let you know my situation of project

i added table view as sub view and table view having 4 section and section having 1,4(dynamic),3,2 rows respectively .
in section=0,textfield is there ,section=2 2 switch button,section=3 both rows are having back ground colours.
these all objects i added through Xib not programmatically ,
when i scroll down colorse are coming in section 0,1,and buttons comming in section 1,2 all getting mess .

```
if (indexPath.section==0) {
  if (indexPath.row==0) {
     self.enterNameTextField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
     self.enterNameTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing =YES;
     self.enterNameTextField.delegate = self;
     self.enterNameTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
     self.enterNameTextField.placeholder=@"Enter youe name";
     self.enterNameTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:  self.enterNameTextField];

     }
     else {
            [self.enterNameTextField removeFromSuperview];
     }            
    }    
 if (indexPath.section==1) {
        NSInteger ii=[self.sectionRows count];
        if(indexPath.row== ii) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Work Out Detail";
        }
        else {
            NSArray *kk=[self.sectionRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"..%@/...index=%d",[self.sectionRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],indexPath.row);
            cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[kk objectAtIndex:2],[kk objectAtIndex:0 ]];
        }
    }
  if (indexPath.section==2) {    
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
            NSInteger taskData;
            taskData=  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"RepetitionCheckMark"];
            self.repitiiondata=[self.listOfRepititionContent objectAtIndex:taskData];
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Repetitions";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=self.repitiiondata;
            NSLog(@"cvxcv%@",self.repitiiondata);
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
            cell.accessoryView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.coolDownSwitch.frame];
            cell.accessoryView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.warmUpSwitch.frame];
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Warm Up(5 min.)";
            int pp=[ self.wrmUpString integerValue];

            if(pp==1) {    
                [self.warmUpSwitch setOn:YES];
            }                
           else {
             [self.warmUpSwitch setOn:NO];
           }
           [cell.accessoryView addSubview:self.warmUpSwitch];

        }

   if (indexPath.row==2) {
            cell.accessoryView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.coolDownSwitch.frame];
            [cell.accessoryView addSubview:self.coolDownSwitch];
            int pp=[ self.coolDwnString integerValue]
            if(pp==1) {                    
                [self.coolDownSwitch setOn:YES];
            }
            else {
                [self.coolDownSwitch setOn:NO];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Cool Down(5 min.)";  
            [cell.accessoryView addSubview:self.coolDownSwitch];
        }
    }        
}   
if (indexPath.section==3) {        
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        cell.textLabel.text=@"            SAVE CONTENT";
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];   
    }
    else {
         cell.textLabel.text=@"            DELETE CONTENT";
         cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];    
         cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];    
     }
  }      
 }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: TIPS: You should add with cell tag

Comment: Can u show entire cellforrow method ?

Comment: Hi @RameshRajput, instead of working indexpath.row, assign tags to each prototype cell in uitableview and work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set you cell identifier as nil.**
This will help you.

Comment: thanks you i tried your way and its working .thank you very very much ,please tell me the concept behind of setting cell identifier to nil .

Comment: It always allocate new cell.

Answer (score 1):

I found difficult to understand your doubt.
But try this.
Give different cellidentifier in xib.
And use diff cell in diff sections
Problem is section 0 is reusing cell from section 2.

Comment: i have setted the cell identifier to nil,and its work well ,one of you    like friend suggest me ,but still i need to know concept behind that .

Comment: Ios do not create all cell. Only those number which are seen at a time. When you scroll cell which goes out is reused below. You give cellIdentifier to a cell. And when you create cell with same Identifier Ios tries to reuse cell. It saves memory. Instead of making cellIdentifier nil give it a different value for each section. And in each cell create cell with those names.